# Why is my python function returning multiple brackets?

Tags: python, recursion, brackets

I'm somewhat of a noob to python but I'm trying to create a recursive function which works just like the built in range function:

```
def Range (lo, hi):
    if lo >= hi:
        return []
    else:
        return [lo, Range (lo+1,hi)]
```

but its returning multiple lists.

Instead of `[3,4,5,6]`, which is what I want, its returning `[3,[4,[5,[6,[]]]]]`
Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you recurse like that, `Range` returns a list each time:

```
Range(3,7)
# translates to
[3, Range(4,7)]
# which translates to
[3, [4, Range(5,7)]]
# etc.
```

In order to avoid this, add your lists together:

```
def Range (lo, hi):
    if lo >= hi:
        return []
    else:
        return [lo] + Range(lo+1, hi)
```

---

**EDIT:**

As @delnan points out, this function is *very* inefficient - it both recurses in a language without tail-call optimization<sup>*</sup> **and** it generates two (possibly *three*) new lists for each level of recursion. @mipadi's answer is more performant because it creates only one list (the `acc` or `accumulator` argument) and passes it as it recurses.

<sup>* This **may** not be true for the Python language, but I'm 99% sure it is true for the most common implementation of Python, namely CPython.</sup>

Comment: This is *extremely* inefficient though. It's a mind-boggingly stupid inefficency too.

Comment: @delnan - absolutely so - I assume that this is for learning about recursion, not building production systems :-) I up-voted mipadi's answer, as I believe it is better than mine (since it makes use of an accumulator to avoid creating multiple lists).  Perhaps I should add his version here too and explain why that's a better way of doing things ...

Comment: @delnan - updated with a note about *why* this is not a good way of doing things, thanks for the comment and let me know if I have left anything out!

Answer (score 3):

Your `Range` function returns a list, so in your last line you are returning a list within a list. What you probably should do is maintain an accumulator and add values to that:

```
def Range(lo, hi, acc=None):
    if acc is None:
        acc = []
    if lo >= hi:
        return acc
    else:
        acc.append(lo)
        return Range(lo+1, hi, acc)
```

Comment: Why not `Range(lo, hi, acc=[])` directly ?

Comment: @Ugo - because you'll wind up with repeated calls to range returning everything that came before - try it and then read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 1):

```
def Range (lo, hi):
    if lo >= hi:
        return []
    else:
        return [lo] + Range (lo+1, hi)
```

but you might get StackOverflow

Comment: Watch out for `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Answer (score 0):

Each recursion into Range returns a list, which is the second element in the list for the previous recursion. Of course [Python has a built-in function for this](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range), but if you want to build it yourself, you probably just want to end with

```
return [lo] + Range(lo+1, hi)
```